# How do I beat Bane on hard?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I've already beaten him on normal, but all his attack do way more damage on hard and it's difficult to beat all the henchmen whist still dodging his attacks.

What's the best tactic to beat him? I assume I need to clear all the henchmen before focusing on him, but they often gang up on me.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the mooks, preferably with combos, counters and takedowns. Even if the visual sign that you can counter doesn't appear, the enemies often will give hints that they will attack. Always keep an eye on Bane. If he throws a rock, dodge quickly to the less crowded side. You can dodge over the henchmen (which will also stun them quickly). If he charges towards you, use Quick Batarang and then dodge to the side. He will crash against the wall and be stunned, when that happens, focus on him and forget the mooks.

With some practice, you can chain all of these actions in the same combo and keep the flow, which will increase your multiplier greatly and allow for easier takedowns.

Comment: Since it's on hard, the counter sign won't flash at all...

Answer (score 2):

I found this fight to be pretty stressful on hard, but one tip I can give in addition to the other useful answers is to use the time you have waiting for Bane or henchmen to place explosive gel in the arena. This way you can clear out a whole wave of henchmen if you're lucky, and that should help you focus more on bane.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that works is keep dodging/evading and let Bane's charges and rock throws hit the henchmen until only a few of them are left. To be sure that the henchmen don't hit you, don't even spend the time to batarang him in this stage. This will take some time and some button mashing however, especially since you're on hard. Once the crowd is cleared, it shouldn't be very different from the first third of the battle.